# How to pass {{x}} into src="{{ url_for('static', filename='photos/x') }}">?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I want to pass variable {{x}} (where the x is a image file name) into jinja template in Flask and use it inside instead of x:
`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='photos/x')}}">`

I have already tried:

```
{{x}}
{% set file_name = 'photos/' + x %}
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=file_name)}}">
```

however, it returns
`<img src="/static/photos/default.png%0D">`
with %0D at the end of the file name and I cant find the way to get rid of it.

Comment: Your code helped me solved my problem, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`%0D` is URI encoded value of newline character

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data

You can either strip it earlier before it reaches the template or in the template in the following way:

```py
{% set file_name = 'photos/' + x.rstrip() %}
```